# Django Install Not Visible - No Errors

Tags: django, passenger

I recently did a successful Django install, and everything went as expected. No errors. But, nothing shows up. It is as if I had never installed Django.

There are no errors. Checking Django/Python versions returns as expected. From the console, I can create new projects/apps, run migrations, create users, etc. Everything seems to work. Except, when I go to mydomain.com, it just loads the old site's index.html as if Django doesn't exist.

I realize the above question isn't a [good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). I figured out my problem *before* posting the question and decided to post my answer below *with* the question for future reference should others have the same issue later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the fruitless task of deleting and recreating my project files, I eventually figured out what happened with my Django installation. I had never enabled Passenger. On the web host in this case, DreamHost, it is just a simple [checkbox in the control panel](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Passenger) to enable, but I never did.

Other than the fact that I should have remembered I need to do enable Passenger for Django to show up, a couple things should have tipped me off. There was no `tmp` folder with a `restart.txt` file. I manually added it (that file's important), but didn't stop to think about why it wasn't there. Also, the html files were loading without being in the `public` folder.

That gave me an hour or so of frustration today, so I thought others might google this later and find this useful. Searching for "Django site has no errors but still doesn't work" wasn't a fruitful avenue for me.